# Unexpected EOF when sending POST request

Tags: http, post, go

I'm having some trouble sending a simple POST request with the http package:

```
var http_client http.Client

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://login.blah", nil)
if err != nil {
  return errors.New("Error creating login request: " + err.Error())
}
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
body := fmt.Sprintf("?username=%s&password=%s&version=%d", client.Username, client.Password, launcherVersion)
fmt.Println("Body:", body)
req.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBufferString(body))
req.ParseForm()
resp, err := http_client.Do(req)

if err != nil {
  return errors.New("Error sending login request: " + err.Error())
}
```

I see the correct body from the print:

```
Body: ?username=test&password=test&version=13
```

But after 60 seconds, I get:

```
Error sending login request: unexpected EOF
```

I'm sure it has something to do with how I set the request body, because watching it with Wireshark shows me the request, which goes out right away, has a `Content-Length` of 0 with no body.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: login.blah
User-Agent: Go http package
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `body` string looks like the end of an URL, just like it would be if you were sending your parameter in a GET request.

The server probably expects the body of your POST request to be in multipart/form-data format  as defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-data-set

I think you should either

- use a [multipart.Writer](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/) to build your body.
- use [PostForm](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.PostForm) as in the package example :

  ```
  resp, err := http.PostForm("http://example.com/form",
      url.Values{"key": {"Value"}, "id": {"123"}})
  ```

Comment: Not sure what I was doing wrong before when I tried http.PostForm, but I just tried again and it seems to have worked! Thanks!